# The RepositoryFactory has already been initialized Exception in tiles and Velocity Integration

Tags: java, spring, exception, velocity, tiles

I am trying to integrate the tiles+ velocity in Spring MVC.

I found the link in [github](https://github.com/pete911/openhouse-web) which was serving the same purpose. So I am using those classes in my Project in Eclispe.
When I run the project I am getting the following exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not initialize VelocityEngine: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The RepositoryFactory has already been initialized!
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not initialize VelocityEngine: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The RepositoryFactory has already been initialized!
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.init(VelocityView.java:354)
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.init(VelocityView.java:310)
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.<init>(VelocityView.java:213)
    org.apache.tiles.velocity.renderer.VelocityAttributeRenderer.commit(VelocityAttributeRenderer.java:82)
    com.me.velo.VelocityTilesContainerFactory.registerAttributeRenderers(VelocityTilesContainerFactory.java:175)
    org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createRendererFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:411)
    org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:111)
    org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
    org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:339)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The RepositoryFactory has already been initialized!
    org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.StringResourceLoader$RepositoryFactory.setRepositoryClass(StringResourceLoader.java:209)
    org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.StringResourceLoader.init(StringResourceLoader.java:99)
    org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.ResourceManagerImpl.initialize(ResourceManagerImpl.java:147)
    org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeResourceManager(RuntimeInstance.java:594)
    org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:241)
    org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine.init(VelocityEngine.java:116)
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.init(VelocityView.java:347)
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.init(VelocityView.java:310)
    org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityView.<init>(VelocityView.java:213)
    org.apache.tiles.velocity.renderer.VelocityAttributeRenderer.commit(VelocityAttributeRenderer.java:82)
    com.me.velo.VelocityTilesContainerFactory.registerAttributeRenderers(VelocityTilesContainerFactory.java:175)
    org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createRendererFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:411)
    org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:111)
    org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
    org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:339)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.35 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
```

I really don't know what that means but after looking at the root cause I found out that
**The RepositoryFactory has already been initialized** is the main reason. 
I am using the classes provided in the repository provided at the github whose link I mentioned above and my servlet-context.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <!-- 
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
     -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.me.velo" />

    <!--  
    <beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
        <beans:property name="order" value="1"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".vm"/>
        <beans:property name="order" value="2"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    -->
    <!-- velocity + tiles initializer -->
<beans:bean id="velocityTilesInitializer" class="com.me.velo.VelocityTilesInitializer">
    <beans:property name="veolocityToolbox" value="/WEB-INF/tools.xml" />
    <beans:property name="veolocityProperties" value="/WEB-INF/velocity.properties" />
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- tiles config with velocityTiles initializer -->
<beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="tilesInitializer" ref="velocityTilesInitializer" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- tiles view -->
<beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass" value="sk.openhouse.web.VelocityTilesView" />
    <beans:property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <!-- default attributes for every view -->
    <beans:property name="attributesMap">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="authentication" value-ref="authenticationService" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

**tiles.xml:**

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

  <tiles-definitions>
  <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/velocity/layout.vm">

             <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
  </definition>

  <definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
             <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/velocity/test.vm" />
  </definition>
  </tiles-definitions>
```

velocity.properties:

```
userdirective=org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.AddAttributeDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.AddListAttributeDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.DefinitionDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.GetAsStringDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.ImportAttributeDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.InsertAttributeDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.InsertDefinitionDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.InsertTemplateDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.PutAttributeDirective,\
  org.apache.tiles.velocity.template.PutListAttributeDirective
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>velocity</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.velocity.tools.view.VelocityViewServlet</servlet-class>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.velocity.toolbox</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tools.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>

  <init-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.velocity.properties</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/velocity.properties</param-value>
  </init-param>

</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>one.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I am not sure what is causing this exception. If anyone has encountered this exception, please help. 
Thanks in advance.